# Splitting data from one column into multiple others

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a problem, one of the tables I am using is set up in a way that is making it hard for me to achieve what I need.

```
index_name  und_mnem   weight     percent_wt  undId   altId     type       
'.SXXP'      'AAL.L'  0.051341648  0.015464   18742  '08238P911 'CUS'
'.SXXP'      'AAL.L'  0.051341648  0.015464   18742  '32508392' 'ISIN'
```

I need to consolidate these two lines into one line with headers CUS and ISIN and the correct altId in the corresponding columns.

Ideally the data would look like this

```
index_name  und_mnem   weight     percent_wt  undId     Cus        ISIN      
'.SXXP'      'AAL.L'  0.051341648  0.015464   18742  '08238P911 '32508392'
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    il.index_name, il.und_mnem, il.weight, il.percent_wt, il.index_shares, 
    il.undId, aa.altId, aa.type 
FROM 
    indexlist il 
join 
    altIdentifier aa on aa.id = il.undId 
where 
    il.index_name = ".SXXP" and type in ("ISIN","CUS")
```

I am using Sybase

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by correct "correct altId"? You must choose one of these two values - for example you can do it select max value

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I have updated my post to hopefully make it a bit clearer, I am using Sybase

Answer (score 0):

```
select il.index_name, il.und_mnem, il.weight, il.percent_wt, il.index_shares, 
        il.undId, cusTbl.cus,isinTbl.isin
from indexlist il join
(select il.undId,aa.altId as cus 
from indexlist il 
    join 
        altIdentifier aa on aa.id = il.undId 
    where 
        il.index_name = ".SXXP" and type="CUS") as cusTbl on il.undId=cusTbl.undId
join
(select il.undId,aa.altId as isin 
from indexlist il 
    join 
        altIdentifier aa on aa.id = il.undId 
    where 
        il.index_name = ".SXXP" and type="ISIN") as isinTbl on il.undId=isinTbl.undId
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
SELECT  il.index_name, 
  il.und_mnem, 
  il.weight, 
  il.percent_wt, 
  il.index_shares, 
  il.undId, 
  max(case when aa.type = 'CUS' then aa.altId end) Cus,
  max(case when aa.type = 'ISIN' then aa.altId end) ISUN
FROM indexlist il 
join altIdentifier aa 
  on aa.id = il.undId 
where il.index_name = ".SXXP" 
  and type in ("ISIN","CUS")
group by il.index_name, il.und_mnem, il.weight, il.percent_wt, 
  il.index_shares, il.undId
```